# How to DRY code that requires $(this) in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to DRY this code:

```
jQuery(function() {

  $(".new-link").hover(
    function(){
      var parent = $(this).parent();
      parent.css("background","#800080");
    },
    function(){
      var parent = $(this).parent();
      parent.css("background","transparent");
      }
    );
});
```

The issue is... I am being unable to define the `parent` variable outside the two anonymous functions, simply because $(this) would be unavailable.

I am not providing lots of specifics. I think those were irrelvant, since this is a theoretical question.

**Short answer:** define `parent` without `var` so it has a global scope.

**Long answers:** above solution may or may not be safe. Use solutions suggested below.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Define the color in a CSS class and toggle the class instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a function that returns another function here:

```
function hoverEvent(color) {
    return function(){
      var parent = $(this).parent();
      parent.css("background",color);
    };
}

jQuery(function() {

  $(".new-link").hover(
    hoverEvent("#800080"),
    hoverEvent("transparent")
    );
});
```

If `parent` isn't needed past this, you can just do `$(this).parent().css("background",color)`.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ladkfnc8/1/

Comment: Kind of unrelated, but defining `parent` isn't really necessary in this case; you can just write `$(this).parent().css("background",color);`.

Comment: Yes, but generally i try to change the original code as little as possible, unless required.

Comment: @Scimonster - but one point of DRY is to remove unnecessary code.  Using object chaining here to remove an unnecessary temporary variable would be relevant to the question.

Comment: @jfriend00 on the other hand, this kind of question doesn't belong on SO in the first place.

Comment: @Mathletics - agreed.

Comment: @jfriend00 would such question completely fit codereview.stackexchange.com ??

Comment: @ZuhaibAli - yes, four of us have already voted to close the question because we think it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com as Mathletics comment on your question says.

Comment: I see. I was wondering there must have been a better place than SO for relatively abstract questions.

Answer (score 1):

Edit, update

Try

v1

```
    (function(elem) {
      $(".new-link").hover(
        function(e){
          elem = $(e.target).parent();
          elem.css("background","#800080");
      }
      , function(e){
          elem.css("background","transparent");
      });
    }(undefined));
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/3p5vtdyb/3/

v2

```
    function evt(e) {
      return $(e.target).parent()
             .css("background" 
             , (e.type === "mouseenter" 
                ? "#800080" 
                : "transparent"));           
    };
    $(".new-link").hover(evt, evt);
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/3p5vtdyb/12/

Comment: This (v1) teaches me exactly how to share a variable across two siblings. The second example has too much magic though... :)